# Popup on Eigen web page blocks content

Tags: eigen

For some reason the Eigen web page now has a popup blocking content.  If you go to http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/, the popup in the upper-left corner of the page doesn't want to go away.  Help please!  Seems to fail with both the latest Firefox and on Chrome.

Comment: That's weird. I see that too. If you use uBlock Origin or something similar you can filter that out, but I think the root cause is a problem with their generated Doxygen HTML. Nothing you can do about that, unless their website code is open-source. I'll check on that.

Comment: Also, I'm not entirely sure that this is on-topic for Stack Overflow. You're new, so don't sweat it, but SO is typically for "a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

Comment: You could consider contacting one of their administrators: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Contributing_to_Eigen

Comment: Thanks.  I started at the Eigen web page but they suggested using stackoverflow instead :-^.  I'll go back there.  This is really frustrating.  It seems to be a new behavior and multiple people on my team are complaining about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Eigen developers are aware of this ([Issue 1918](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1918)) and they just [merged a fix](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/merge_requests/148) about 5 minutes ago. I'm not sure how long it takes to update the website, but the documentation bug causing the issue should be fixed.

Apparently the issue was with the JavaScript in `eigen_navtree_hacks.js` which needed the `load` function (which is deprecated) to be changed to the `on` function

```
 $(window).load(showRoot);
```

had to be changed to

```
 $(window).on("load", showRoot);
```

and

```
$(window).load(resizeHeight);
```

had to be changed to

```
$(window).on("load", resizeHeight);
```

I'm not sure what actually triggered the menu to start behaving this way in the first place.

Comment: Not fixed on Firefox 78.0.2 (Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: @RL-S Yeah, it looks like the hosted website still doesn't have the latest version of the docs. I just checked with the Chrome dev tools and it is still using the old buggy Javascript file (see line 140 of eigen_navtree_hacks.js in your browser and compare it to https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/doc/eigen_navtree_hacks.js). If you want to be able to navigate the HTML docs without the annoying menu overlay, I recommend cloning the repo and building the docs locally.