# Popup window blocking the reading of Eigen documentatoin web pages

Tags: popup, eigen

On the contrary to what was mentioned in a previous post ([Popup on Eigen web page blocks content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539911/popup-on-eigen-web-page-blocks-content)), on July 17th, 2020, it seems that Eigen documentation web pages still have a popup on the top left side blocking the reading.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have the same problem on Firefox 78.0.2, Ubuntu 20.04. What browser and OS are you using?